# Drupal Views argument menu - sending %! to end of URL

Tags: drupal, view, arguments, hyperlink

Im building this project managment site that uses organic groups to sort and name projects.

So I have example.com/project/6. Where 6 is the organic groups views argument of %1.

What I am struggling to do is be able to create links that send for example 'gallery' to the end of the URL so example.com/project/6/gallery would show the gallery for project 6.

I am trying to create a global menu where all items would work for any organic group you may be within. So if you were within project 5 (http://example.com/project/5) the same menu item of 'Gallery' could be used to display example.com/project/5/gallery.

I have tried with all normal drupal menu methods but %1 is never accepted. 
The main thing is to be able to send for example '/gallery' to the end of the URL, or use any other method to achieve this.

Hope I have explained myself correctly.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [block](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/block) plus [view](http://drupal.org/project/views), assuming all your gallery rests in its own custom content type, put the view inside the block while using arguments to control what is displayed.

The basic structure look like this:

- Page example.com/project/6
- load page project 6 normal content block
- load block gallery, argument read the url end with 6,
- load pictures related to that node.